# Plot points by Latitude and Longitude in Highmaps

Tags: highmaps

I am trying to plot missing countries on the Highmaps world high resolution map. However it is difficult to get the correct co-ordinates.

It appears this may be difficult because the charts do not correspond with latitude and longitude. For example world high-resolution has 1750 points on the X axis, so half is 875, but GMT is at about 839.

Ideally I am looking for a formula that can be used to convert latitude and longitude to x/y, but do not know how to do this.

Comment: You won't be able to do this with some maps, like the world map, as the points do not necessarily correspond to lat,lng. E.g. the world map has Alaska on one side and Eastern Siberia on one side, while they actually overlap. So there is no way to plot by lat,lng for that map, but for other maps you can probably get the lat,lng of the four corners of the map and then divide by the number of points to get the number of points per lat or lng.